# When to use Central Limit Theorem or Cramers Theorem

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, parameter-estimation

In for example [this paper](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~srikant/ECE567/Fall09/cramer-many-sources.pdf) the authors say

> The central limit theorem provides an estimate of the probability
>   \begin{align}
> P\left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - n\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} > x \right)
> \end{align}
>   ... the CLT estimates the probability of $O(\sqrt{n})$ deviations from the mean of the sum of random variables ... On the other hand, large deviations of the order of the mean itself, i.e., $O(n)$ deviations, is the subject of this section [Cramer-Chernoff Theorem].

It is not clear to my why the CTL can't be used to calculate large deviations. Following the answer of [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/995874/148666) for large $n$, the CTL tells me, that the mean is approximately normally distributed as
$$P\left(|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - n\mu| \geq x\right) \approx 2\Phi\left(-\frac{x \sqrt{n}}{\sigma}\right)$$

Why (and in which cases) should Cramers theorem be used if $x$ is large and not the CTL?

Comment: My simplest explanation is that the Central Limit Theorem gives a small absolute error in calculating the probability, and this tends to get smaller with larger $n$ (notably when $x/\sqrt{n}$ is held constant so the approximation does not change) but this does not provide an assurance of small relative error when the probability is tiny as it is with large deviations.

Comment: @Manuel The $x$ in the LHS of your last formula should be $nx$. But then the asymptotics given by the RHS is quite wrong since CLT and large deviations principle apply to deviations of $S_n$ from its mean of different magnitudes, respectively $\sqrt{n}$ and $n$. To apply one in the regime of the other may result in wrong asymptotics, for example the one at the end of your post is probably only true when the $X_n$s are normal.

Answer (score 1):

Large deviation gives you an estimate of the probabilities in the non-typical regime, whereas CLT gives you an estimate of the probabilities in the typical regime. Suppose $X_i$ have finite variance and are a.s. positive. Then CLT gives,
$$
|P(\frac{\sum_i X_i  - n\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} \ge x) - \Phi(-x)| \to 0.
$$
But CLT does'nt say anything if you let $x$ grow with $n$ as well. Say you want to know $P(\sum_i X_i - n\mu >\mu n)$ and $X_i$'s are all positive a.s. Then replacing $x$ by $\sqrt{n} \mu/\sigma$ would give you an approximation of this probability as $e^{-cn}$ from some $c>0$. But this would not be correct. Lets say, $X_i$ have a very heavy tail, $P(X_i > n) \ge n^{-4}$. Then if $X_1 >2n\mu$ then $\sum_{i \le n}X_i > 2n\mu$ and hence
$$
P(|\sum_{i \le n}X_i - n\mu| > n\mu) \ge P(\sum_{i \le n}X_i > 2n\mu)  \ge P(X_1 > 2n\mu) \ge (2n\mu)^{-4}
$$
and you do not get an exponential bound, but a polynomial bound.

Comment: "Large deviation is more precise" No. "Then we know via CLT..." Sorry but we know nothing of the sort of what you write afterwards. As a matter of fact, if we "knew" what you write, every action of every large deviation principle would be quadratic.

Comment: Sorry, I was careless with my writing. I have edited my answer.